# How to inspect a Kendo multiselect?

Tags: google-chrome, kendo-ui, web-inspector

I am developing automation for a page that has a kendo multiselect dropdown checklist.

Normally I rely on the Chrome inspector dev tool to determine the Xpath of the elements I am accessing.

However I'm hitting a catch-22 (or perhaps more accurately, the Uncertainty Principle) when I attempt to inspect a Kendo multiselect. The procedure I follow is...

1. Preconditions:
   1a) browser is open to a page that contains a Kendo multiselect
   1b) Chrome inspector is active
2. Click on the search bar of the Kendo Multiselect. This results in the expansion of a dropdown-like list of the possible multiselect items (each having its own checkbox). It is kind of a hybrid checkbox list embedded in a pulldown list. Very convenient for the end user.
3. Now that the list is expanded, I want to explore, let's say, the DOM at or around the third element of the list. My ultimate goal is to determine the Xpath for that third element of the multiselect list. No problem ... I've got the list expanded and all I need do is click on the element selector icon in the Chrome inspector window and then point to the third element in the browser window.

But not so fast ....

4. Here's the problem... as soon as I click on the element selector icon in the Chrome inspector window, the multiselect list collapses (!) and, of course, with it, the DOM is updated accordingly and the element I had hoped to inspect isn't even in the DOM because of the updated state of the multiselect list.

4a. As a potential workaround, I attempted the hot-key equivalent of clicking on the Chrome inspector's element selector icon (Ctrl-Shift-C). This worked only partially: while the multiselect list didn't collapse, I wasn't able to figure out *where* in the DOM the resulting match resided - because as soon as I scroll up/down or do any other mouse or keyboard activity, the dang multiselect list collapses.

WTF?

I guess what I'm looking for is some way to isolate mouse clicks in the Chrome inspector window from the inspectee window. I haven't been faced with this requirement in the past, so I have no clue how to proceed.

I have found some references to remote inspection, and I wonder if this is my solution. But it was not at all clear to me that it would solve my issue. Rather than chase that rabbit down a potentially never-ending rabbit hole, I chose to post this here question in hope of receiving some sage advice relevant to my conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

With the Dev Tools open on the Sources tab, open the MultiSelect box and hit F8. This will pause everything and everything will turn gray.

Now you can switch to the Elements tab in Dev Tools and do whatever you want and nothing on the page will change.

When you're done, hit F8 again or click the "Play" button on the Sources tab in Dev Tools.

Answer (score 0):

You may have more luck with right-clicking on the item and selecting "inspect". While the multiselect may collapse, you should still be able to catch the element in the DOM. (I'm assuming Kendo for jQuery?)

If you have only one MultiSelect on your page, this gives you:

```
$(".k-animation-container .k-list-container.k-popup li:nth-child(3)");
```

If you can edit the code, temporarily setting [autoClose](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect/configuration/autoclose) to false may help you. You can also bind to the various [events](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#events) Kendo exposes and put some debugging code there.

One last trick is to catch a node in the DOM inspector, in this case div.k-animation-container which should be a direct child of body, and right click > break on > attribute modifications. This can pause your code too often, but it's a good tool to have in your belt in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions didn't solve my problem, the multiselect continued to collapse every time I attempted to inspect it. For example, the mere act of pressing F8 causes the multiselect to collapse.

However, I did find a simple solution. I had been using an inspector window that was docked to the browser window. This appears to result in keyboard and mouse activity to be shared by both the inspectee browser window and the inspector window.

But when I undock the inspector I am able to click, for example, on the select-an-element-in-the-page-to-inspect-it icon without causing any activity in the page being inspected - including the multiselect. Now I am able to hover over each of the multiselect items and inspect them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome Developer Tools break on subtree change or attribute change for the element. The process is well described in the following blog post:

https://camerondwyer.com/2018/07/11/how-to-inspect-dynamic-html-elements-that-keep-disappearing-in-chrome/